# Saving HTML in database

Tags: php

I have a page that is written in HTML, I want to add a \ before every " and remove them before writing the code to the page.

How can I perform this?

NOTE: I use `file_get_contents("file.php");` to get the contents of the file to be added to the database.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Do you want to display the *HTML souce* on the page?

Comment: @Alexandre Jasmin: I want to store a page source in a database, and then get the source from the database and display it as HTML page.

Comment: Can you explain why do you need the slashes? I think i gave the correct answer, but you don't know yet. :)

Comment: @c0rnh0li0: to use it in the query!

Comment: Well, then use mysql_real_escape_string. It escapes the string appropriate and securely for a mysql db. Other databases have quote or escape functions too, if you don't use mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) on any value you want to write to your database.

Comment: asuming he uses a database and made a successfull connection to it, otherwise mysql_real_escape_string() won't help him. And it only add's a backslash and does not remove it

Comment: He wants to write to a database and if so he needs a successful connection. :) Also mysql_real_escape_string doesn't need the slashes to be removed.

Comment: I want to add a \ before every " to be able to process the string from php and then store the string in the database. And I want to remove every \ that exists before " when reading form the database.

Comment: You don't need to escape the " to process it in php and mysql_real_escape_string is the right tool to escape it for the database.

Answer (score 0):

use `addslashes()` to add the \ and then `stripslashes()` to remove them again.

edit: pass in as parameter your html code for each function

Comment: @kirke: you mean addslashes("something"askdnh") will give "something\"askdnh" and the stripslashes("something\"askdnh") will give "something"askdnh"?

Comment: @sikas yes something like that. Better store it in a variable first and then pass it as parameter. eg: $html = 'something"askdnh'; and then pass it like this addslashes($html)

Comment: @kirke: I have the text now passed form a form $_POST['myText'], I have tried str_replace('"','\"',$_POST['myText']); yet the output is still the same!

Comment: @kirke: I have also tried addslashes($_POST['myText']); didn`t work also!!